# Mongoose $in not working in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a collection containing some operation details like below

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580776455ecd3b4352705ec4"), "operation_number" : 10, "operation_description" : "SHEARING", "machine" : "GAS CUTT" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580776455ecd3b4352705ec5"), "operation_number" : 50, "operation_description" : "EYE ROLLING -1", "machine" : "E-ROLL-1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580776455ecd3b4352705ec6"), "operation_number" : 60, "operation_description" : "EYE ROLLING -2", "machine" : "E-ROLL-1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580776455ecd3b4352705ec7"), "operation_number" : 70, "operation_description" : "EYE REAMING", "machine" : "E-REAM" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580776455ecd3b4352705ec8"), "operation_number" : 80, "operation_description" : "COLD CENTER HOLE PUNCHING", "machine" : "C-PNCH-1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("580776455ecd3b4352705ec9"), "operation_number" : 150, "operation_description" : "READY FOR HT", "machine" : "RHT" }
```

using mongoose model as below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var Promise = require("bluebird");

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var operationSchema = new Schema({
    operation_number: {
        type: String,
        required: [
            true,
            "Please select valid operation code"
        ]unique : true
    },
    operation_description: {
        type: String,
        required: [
            true,
            "Please select valid operation description"
        ]
     }
}, { strict: false });
var operation = mongoose.model('operation', operationSchema);
operationSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: 'Error, {PATH} {VALUE} already exist.' });


// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = operation;
```

now if I query this collection `operations` using `db.operations.find({operation_number : {$in : [10, 50, 60]}})` it works but when it comes to mongoose it's not working.

```
var mc = require("./data-models/operation")
var filter = {'operation_number': 
                {$in : 
                    [10, 50, 60]
                }
            }
console.log(filter)
mc.find(filter, function(me, md){
    console.log(me, md) // prints null []
})
```

Even I've tried removing single quotes around `operation_number`

Please help finding way !

Comment: Can you append the model declaration from `./data-models/operation` to the post?

Comment: Yes please attach the schema model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your schema says that `operation_number` is a string:

```
operation_number: {
    type: String, <-- here
    ...
}
```

Therefore, Mongoose will cast the numbers in the `$in` array to strings.

However, the data in the database is numerical, which is a different type. You should change your schema so that `operation_number` becomes a `Number`:

```
operation_number: {
    type: Number,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that you forget to define that attribute in the schema.